# Add a new page number format to Microsoft Word drop down menu

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a particular style of page number formatting that I like to use for certain documents.  I would like to add it to the drop down menu under Insert > Page Number.  Is that possible?

I have Word 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you first need decide where you want to be able to use your style: in page headers, in page footers, in page margins, and/or just wherever you happen to have the cursor.

1. Select the page number in your custom style, together with any graphics or shapes that go with it.
2. If you have the header or footer open, so that the **Header & Footer Tools** > **Design** tab is displayed, in the **Header & Footer** group, select **Page Number**, select one of the location options, and then select **Save Selection as Page Number**.

   If you don't have the header or footer open, the **Page Number** button that you need is in the **Header & Footer** group on the **Insert** tab.
3. Adjust the settings in the dialog box as you require, or accept the default settings.
4. If you want the style to be usable in more than one page location, make any location-specific changes that are required, and then repeat steps 2 and 3, selecting a different location option in step 2.